# no data gets print where the query returns too many results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which is supposed to retrieve data from mysql and print it on the browser. It is working with a few rows of data but when the data gets bigger it just stops working and doesn't give any errors.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);


$json_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json_array[] = $row;
}

print mysql_error();
print json_encode($json_array);
```

I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Maybe it reached to maximum allowed memory usage or maximum allowed run time. What is your query? is it optimized? how many records its returned?

Comment: Please don't expose your PHP Info like that it's risky for your server

Comment: `mysql_*()` was deprecated in PHP5.6 and removed from PHP 7. You shouldn't use it for new code. Update your code to use `mysqli_*()` or better, `PDO`

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (2013), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0 (2015). Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: If its not giving any results because of too much data, then it is giving errors - you just can't see them. Look harder. BTW you should not still be using this version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very surprised it works at all.

This would work if $row was formatted.

Use `foreach()`

I doubt this would work either:

```
foreach($json_array as $row){
  echo "$row<br>\n"
}
```

This should work (replace colx with the name of the table columns):

```
foreach($json_array as $row){
  echo $row['col1'] . ', ' . $row['col2'] . ', ' . $row['col2'] . "<br>\n"
}


foreach($json_array as $row){
  echo $row['name'] . ', ' . $row['address'] . ', ' . $row['phone'] . "<br>\n"
}
```

Comment: erm, no. Not buffering the result *MAY* help with the output, but if that were the issue, then you'd need to use regular flushes to avoid filling the PHP memory. And the code here will not produce json encoded data.

Comment: @symcbean No not true.  The burden would be on the Browser, not PHP.   And who said there is a lot of data?  It is assume the JSON is coming from the table.   So how is it you think my routine will use gobs of memory?  If there is too much data then the echo should be in the SQL loop.  The OP's code would never work and it's not that clear what is going on.  I just try to help.  I do not get on a high horse and criticize others.

Comment: Sorry, but what you are saying here is completely wrong. And OP states that the issue is related to the volume of data.

Answer (score 0):

@Lessmore has right, maybe the PHP process has reached the memory limits in the server, try with less columns or registers, but I understand your need, then you need to write your self json_encode code to write row by row. Some like this:

```
    $first = null;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo '[';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($first) {
            echo ',';
        }
        echo json_encode($row);
        !$first && $first = true;
    }
    echo ']';
    exit;
```